# htaccess URL Rewrite - Root to Subfolder (with folder of the same name)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file at www.domain.com/blog/blog.html that I want to rewrite as www.domain.com/blog.

I have figured out the rewrite for removing the extension .html but am having either circular issues or end up pointing the blog rewrite to the blog folder when trying to do the above.

I am new to rewrite syntax, so help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `/blog/.htaccess` if it doesn't already exist and place this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^/?$ blog.html [L]

# To internally forward /blog/file to /blog/file.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: This now gives me: www.domain.com/blog/ - how do I remove the trailing slash? Also, now I can't access the pages in the subfolder i.e. www.domain.com/blog/1506.

Comment: No, but I have a rewrite rule to remove the .html extension of all the files in the root folder .htaccess.

Comment: Yes, I have a directory /blog/ in which there is the html file blog.html and others such as 1506.html, 1505.html etc.

Comment: That has worked for the other files (thanks!) but www.domain.com/blog/blog.html still rewrites as www.domain.com/blog/ - how do I remove the trailing slash?

Comment: Oh trailing slash after `blog/` is there because `blog` is a directory and Apache's `mod_dir` module adds it even if you remove it. There are security reasons of having a slash after a real directory.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense and I think I can live with that seeing as the request www.domain.com/blog still takes me to the page. Thanks for all of your help, it has been great!